# Jquery Initiated Download Returning 'Failed: Network Error'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a JQuery AJAX request that will trigger a download upon its completion.

**CODE:**

```
 $('.getPDF').click(function(){
 var filepath = 'localhost:3000/pdf/formula-' + this.id + '.pdf';
 $.ajax({
   url: '/formulas/'+ this.id +'/pdf',
   type: 'POST',
   success: downloadFile(filepath)
 });

 function downloadFile (path) {
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = path;
   $(link).attr("download", true);
   link.click();
   }
 });
```

This returns the following error in Chrome:

```
Failed - Network Error
```

with nothing else showing up in the console.  The download does not work in Firefox or IE either.

I've done a `console.log(filepath)` in success, and the route it returns shows the correct file when I paste it into the browser-bar as a URL.

The HTML generating the AJAX Request looks like this:

```
<a class="pure-button button-success getPDF" id="59ac514a52c93e4aa862fadd">Generate PDF </a>
```

If it's relevant, the server side code generically looks like this:

```
router.post('/formulas/:id/pdf', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db.collection('users');
  var id = new ObjectID(req.params.id);
  var pointer = {"formulas.$": 1, "_id": 0};
  db.aggregate([
    {$match: {"formulas.f_id": id}},
    {$unwind: "$formulas"},
    {$match: {"formulas.f_id": id}},
    {$project : {"formulas": 1, "_id": 0}}
  ]).toArray(function(e, doc){
    if (e) {
    throw e;
  } else {
    var html = null;
   ejs.renderFile('./views/pdf.ejs', {
    project: doc[0].formulas
  }, function(err, results){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      }
      html = results;
    });
    var options = { format: 'Letter' };
    var path = 'public/pdf/formula-' + req.params.id + '.pdf';
    pdf.create(html, options).toFile(path, function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      if (results) {
        res.end();
      }
    });
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: The `downloadFile` isn't called on success, but right away, seeing as you've included the parentheses. That shouldn't really matter though? Do you have a static route that actually serves up the PDF you're trying to download

Comment: @adeneo - yes, I've tested the static route and it serves the file correctly.

Comment: Heve you tried adding the protocol? Since `filepath` is used in an anchor href... Maybe... `var filepath = 'http://localhost:3000/pdf/formula-' + this.id + '.pdf';`

Comment: Why not post how Node returns the PDF, as that seems to be where the error is, hence a network error ?

Comment: I think that `filepath` may be overwritten by the ajax response... Try this: `success: function(response){ downloadFile(filepath); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ajax success callback has to be a function...
The first argument can be named as you wish... But will be filled with the Ajax response.

So the response is overwriting your `filepath` variable...
To avoid this, call `downloadFile` within a callback function.
And just ignore the response if you don't need it. ;)

```
success: function(response){
  downloadFile(filepath);
}
```